# How to make sure that a file exists in my svn repository but no commits are allowed?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a few files that I want to exist in my svn repository but I don't want any information contained within. Developers with the file always have local changes, but their changes should not be allowed within the repository. Some of the files should actually just be empty.

I figured that an svn lock would be something to use but whoever has the lock can still commit changes. I want the devs to be able to make local changes, sure, but just not commit them. Is there a method for forcing a file to exist but not allowing any changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a server side way. You can do it [locally on a TortoiseSVN client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635446/1318694). As mentioned in that answer command line SVN doesn't do this automatically so would need an additional changelist option added to obey the ignore.

Maybe do both. Lock the file with an unused SVN account. Then whenever a dev complains, point them at [the setup info for how to ignore that file](http://blog.baljeetsingh.net/2009/02/tips-tricks-svn-ignore-on-commit.html).

Comment: I did not know of that ignore-on-commit option, it works well enough for me. And a nice idea with the lock as well, I'll do this. I didn't think to look for this on SO because it was the wrong site to ask this as far as I know and it didn't show up with the Google machine so I never saw that QA. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You will find a lot of answers on SO before the other communities were split out.